# Работа с массивом из PictureBox (получение контрола, сгенерировавшего событие)

Tags: c#, winforms

Как сделать так, чтобы для каждого `PictureBox` происходило событие `PictureBox.Click`, изменяющее свойство именно этого элемента (например `PictureBox.BackColor`)?

Код создания массива из `PictureBox`:

```
private void CreateSell(int SideSize)
{
    PicturesArray = new PictureBox[SideSize, SideSize];
    this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(20 + (5 * SideSize - 1) + (40 * SideSize),
        32 + 10 + (5 * SideSize - 1) + (40 * SideSize));
    for (int i = 0; i < SideSize; i++)
    {
        for (int n = 0; n < SideSize; n++)
        {
            Point point = new Point();
            point.Y = 5 + 5 * i + 40 * i;
            point.X = 5 + 5 * n + 40 * n;
            this.PicturesArray[i, n] = new PictureBox();
            this.PicturesArray[i, n].Width = 40;
            this.PicturesArray[i, n].Height = 40;
            this.PicturesArray[i, n].Location = point;
            this.PicturesArray[i, n].BackColor = Color.Black;
            this.PicturesArray[i, n].Click += Pic_Click;
            this.Controls.Add(PicturesArray[i, n]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У событий не просто так два аргумента: `object sender` и `EventArgs args`. Первый аргумент содержит объект, который сгенерировал событие. То есть в вашем случае:

```
void Pic_Click (object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    var pic = (PictureBox)sender;
    pic.BackColor = MyFavoriteBackColor;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Я то думал не спроста же есть `object sender`. Однако не знал, что можно так преобразовать.